# Alternatives to a shared list between threads (multiprocessing)

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I need to access elements of a list from processes spawned by the multiprocessing library. However I have read that it is a bad idea to have a shared data structure between processes, But I am not sure how else to go about this problem. The list contains counter variables, which each need to be accessed by the processes. The counter variables within the list need to be incremented by the loops inside each process. I am looking for an alternative to creating a shared lists between the processes. I have unsuccesfully tried to create a shared list between processes shown in the code below. Any alternative methods/assistance with the errors produced would be appreciated.

```
with Manager() as manager:
    aout_stable = manager.list([0]*len(aout))

def calculate(ain_index_):
    ainn= ain[ain_index_]
    for parameters in itertools.product(aout,qoutlist,samples_eccentricities):
        #Finding index for which counter variable to increment within list
        aout_index = np.where(aout==parameters[0])[0][0]
        a_ratio = parameters[0]/ainn
        inclination_limit = (math.pi/0.3)*(1-a_ratio/((( (1+parameters[1])*(1+parameters[2])/(np.sqrt(1-parameters[2]) ))**(2./5.) )*(2.8/(1-parameters[2]))))
        stable_num = len(np.where(inclinations>inclination_limit)[0])
        aout_stable[aout_index] += stable_num

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=20)
ain_index = [i for i in range(len(ain))]
result = pool.map(calculate,ain_index)
```

The error returned by the unsuccesful code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "itertools test.py", line 82, in <module>
    result = pool.map(calculate,ain_index)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
socket.error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Just running the calculate function over one element of the ain array instead of across the entire array produces the following error:

```
  File "itertools test.py", line 80, in <module>
    x = calculate(1)
  File "itertools test.py", line 71, in calculate
    aout_stable[aout_index] += stable_num
  File "<string>", line 2, in __getitem__
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 755, in _callmethod
    self._connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 742, in _connect
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 169, in Client
    c = SocketClient(address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 304, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```